# TranslateX breaks sticky navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

So i made a sticky navbar to stick on top of a page, on the page i have paragraps and elements that i give css like

```
.from-left{
     transform: translateX(-80%); } .from-right{
     transform: translateX(80%); } .from-left,.from-right{
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in, transform 1000ms ease-in;
    opacity: 0; } .from-left.appear,.from-right.appear{
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1; }
```

I then use intersection observer to give them appear class so that they slide in. Works fine if firefox, chrome however makes my navbar not stick to the top until all the elements slide in into their place, once they slide in navbar sticks to the top and works. I got no clue why this works in firefox and not in chrome and how to fix it, guess i could make elements positions absolute and rewrite stuff but i would like to avoid that.

Comment: Please provide a complete snippet or demo. No one likes trying to debug through a straw.

Comment: Hmm interesting, tried to put it on codepen but it worked there, used bootstrap twitter or someting, perhaps thats the issue T_T